# How can I step into(F11) only my project souce files in visual c++?

Tags: visual-studio

I use visual c++.
When I pressed <kbd>F11</kbd> key for debugging, I step into default source file like "stdio.h".
I want to step into only my source file except default source files of visual c++.
I can't find option in visual studio.
Somebody helps me.